# How to Maintain a Common data over windowsphones?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am creating an offline app,which have a table of data(SQL)..And that data must be in all the phone using my app...The Application must update this table whenever the phone gets connected to Internet.The Users can insert,update but cant delete their data in the table.

I want this table to be in a common place and store the table to Isolated Storage for offline usage .In my search I found that we can do this through OData with SQLAzure in cloud..I do want to know is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sql-ce` dabatabase from `mango` which is stored in `IsolatedStorage`.

[Here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7.1-Local-SQL-Database.aspx) is good article.

For online updating I always use custom webservices running on my server, which is not that hard to develop.